# Sum up values from a dictionary (the Python way)

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the following dictionary, let's call it `mydict`

```
 {'Plekhg2': {'Bcells': '233.55', 'DendriticCells': '190.12'}, 
  'Barxxxx': {'Bcells': '132.11', 'DendriticCells': '92.01'}, }
```

I want to sum up values for each key from inner dictionary, resulting in:

```
 {'Plekhg2': 423.67,  # 233.55 + 190.12
  'Barxxxx': 224.12}  # 132.11 + 92.01
```

How can I achieve that with Python idiom?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a dict comprehension, using `sum()` to sum the nested dictionary values; Python 2.6 or before would use `dict()` and a generator expression:

```
# Python 2.7
{k: sum(float(f) for f in v.itervalues()) for k, v in mydict.iteritems()}
# Python 3.x
{k: sum(map(float, v.values())) for k, v in mydict.items()}
# Python 2.6 and before
dict((k, sum(float(f) for f in v.values())) for k, v in mydict.iteritems())
```

You may want to store float values to begin with though.

Demo:

```
>>> mydict ={'Plekhg2': {'Bcells': '233.55', 'DendriticCells': '190.12'}, 
...   'Barxxxx': {'Bcells': '132.11', 'DendriticCells': '92.01'}, }
>>> {k: sum(float(f) for f in v.itervalues()) for k, v in mydict.iteritems()}
{'Plekhg2': 423.67, 'Barxxxx': 224.12}
```

Comment: Is this Python2 or 3? I'm using Python2.

Comment: @neversaint: Python 2.7. Are you using Python 2.6 or older perhaps?

Comment: Python 2.6.2. I got this message ` {k: sum(float(f) for f in v.itervalues()) for k, v in mydict.iteritems()}
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Answer (score 4):

Use a dict comprehension and `sum`, since the values are strings you'll have to convert them to floats first using `float`.

```
>>> {k:sum(float(x) for x in v.itervalues()) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
{'Plekhg2': 423.67, 'Barxxxx': 224.12}
```

For Python 3 use `.items()` and `.values()` instead of the `.iter(values|items)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion in Python 3:

```
In [134]:

{k:sum(float(x) for x in v.values()) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
Out[134]:
{'Barxxxx': 224.12, 'Plekhg2': 423.67}
```